# AngularJS: ngClass not updating on ngClick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

I have a ngRepeat function to print some divs which the first one has the **active** class by default and on div click I want to set the div clicked **active** and the other ones with the **inactive** class and I have the next code but I don't know why is not working.

**In my controller**

```
$scope.activeSection = 0;
```

**In my view**

```
<div ng-repeat="div in divs" ng-class="activeSection == $index ? 'active' : 'inactive'" ng-click="activeSection = $index">
    <p>Lorem......</p>
</div>
```

The problem here is when I do click, the div clicked becomes active but is not changing the last activated div to **inactive** and keeps the **active** class instead.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-repeat defines its own scope. So when `activeSection = $index`, what is set the the ng-repeat's activeSection variable. Not the controller's activeSection variable.

To solve the problem, define an object in the controller scope:

```
$scope.sectionModel = {}
```

And in the view, use

```
ng-class="sectionModel.activeSection == $index ? 'active' : 'inactive'" ng-click="sectionModel.activeSection = $index"
```

Or use a function in the controller scope to change the value of `activeSection`.

BTW, instead of saving the *index* of the active section, I would store the active section itself. This makes sure that your ng-repeat would work fine even if it uses a filter that changes the number of the order of the sections:

```
$scope.activeSection = null; // or $scope.div[0] for example
$scope.setActiveSection = function(section) {
    $scope.activeSection = section;
}

<div ng-repeat="div in divs | orderBy:'title'" ng-class="activeSection === div ? 'active' : 'inactive'" ng-click="setActiveSection(div)">
    <p>Lorem......</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Btw, could you please tell me how can I store the active section instead use the index?

Answer (score 1):

The reason being, `ngRepeat` will create its own `$scope` - so you're not actually updating the `activeSection` you think you are - you're creating another variable called `activeSection` on the `ngRepeat` scope (child). One way around this is to use `$parent` (ugly) - or just call a function on your controller to ensure the right `$scope` is reached:

```
$scope.setActive = function(index) {
    $scope.activeSection = index;
}
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="div in divs" ng-class="activeSection == $index ? 'active' : 'inactive'" ng-click="setActive($index)">
    <p>Lorem......</p>
</div>
```

Definitely read this post regarding `$scope` and inheritance: [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

Comment: Or use controllerAs and bind to, for example, vm.activeSection

Comment: I see now, thanks for the explanation but unfortunately is not working.